# Switch Fragment(Show/Hide) with bottom bar Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have problem with implement fragment and bottom bar on my apps..

I wan to switch fragment according initialize bottom bar..
this my code

```
    private Fragment frag_summary = new SummaryFragment();
    private Fragment frag_my_proposal = new MyProposalFragment();
    private Fragment frag_proposal = new ProposalFragment();
    private Fragment frag_friends = new FriendsFragment();

bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
                setSelectedFragment(tabId);
            }
        });


    public void setSelectedFragment(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.menu_home:
                setFragment(id, frag_summary);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_my_proposals:
                setFragment(id, new MyProposalFragment());
                break;
            case R.id.menu_proposal:
                setFragment(id, new ProposalFragment());
                break;
            case R.id.menu_friends:
                setFragment(id, new FriendsFragment());
                break;
            case R.id.menu_more:
               /* drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }*/
                break;
            default:
                setFragment(id, frag_summary);
                break;

        }
    }

    private void setFragment(int id, Fragment fragments) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        String fragmentTag = String.valueOf(id);

        if (frag_summary.isAdded()) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(frag_summary);
        }
        if (frag_my_proposal.isAdded()) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(frag_my_proposal);
        }
        if (frag_proposal.isAdded()) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(frag_proposal);
        }
        if (frag_friends.isAdded()) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(frag_friends);
        }
        if (fragments.isAdded()) {
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragments);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragments, fragmentTag);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();


    }
```

The Issue is : When I selected from Fragment frag_summary to Fragment frag_friends, Fragment frag_summary and other fragment sometimes still showed.. like other activity ex: from Fragment frag_friends to Fragment frag_proposal .

sho how to fix it ?
sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Repalce the code in `setFragment` with  -

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragments, fragmentTag);
fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Basically you are replacing the current visivble fragment.

Edit : Change the code as below -

```
public void setSelectedFragment(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.menu_home:
                setFragment(id, frag_summary);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_my_proposals:
                setFragment(id, /*send the class instance you created for this fragment */);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_proposal:
                setFragment(id, /*send the class instance you created for this fragment */);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_friends:
                setFragment(id, /*send the class instance you created for this fragment */);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_more:
               /* drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }*/
                break;
            default:
                setFragment(id, frag_summary);
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but i want switch without reload again of fragment. I want switch with last condition of fragment...

Comment: The suggestion i gave would also work. But yor real problem is that instead of passing the instance variables while calling `setFragment`, you are sending a new instance of each fragment. I edited my answer